# React navigation header button: go to another screen but with props from a certain screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a screen file that holds a stack navigation with 3 screens: Restaurants, Details, Edit. I have it so that only the Details header has an edit button, but since the header properties are controlled in the main screen file, I'm not sure how I can navigate to the edit screen but with props from the details screen.

Comment: explore this doc : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component

Comment: You should provide some code so that its easy to understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @TusharPandey Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can lift the state up from details to main. Refer this
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html